# How to update Opera browser?

Tags: opera

No update of the Opera package.

Opera 30
Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo aptitude -f install
```

gives me:

> Es werden keine Pakete installiert, aktualisiert oder entfernt.
>   0 Pakete aktualisiert, 0 zusätzlich installiert, 0 werden entfernt und 1 nicht aktualisiert.
>   0 B an Archiven müssen heruntergeladen werden. Nach dem Entpacken werden 0 B zusätzlich belegt sein.

Any idea someone ?

Comment: Did you install Opera via their repository or downloaded the package from their page? It looks like 30 *is* the current version, so I'm not really sure what issue you do have.

Comment: Version: 30.0.1835.59 - Eine neue Version (a new version) von 30.0.1835.88 ist verfügbar (is available). I dont remember the way I installed sinced it was long ago. I guess it was the package from the website. All worked fine. Now the system gives me a message for the available update but I cant tick the box for the package.

Comment: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS) (x86_64; Unity)

Answer (score 7):

The current stable version of Opera browser is:

```
opera-stable_30.0.1835.88
```

The current beta version is:

```
opera-beta_31.0.1889.50
```

And the developer version is:

```
opera-developer_32.0.1910.0
```

To add Opera repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list' 
wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

The packages in repository:

> opera-beta
>   opera-developer
>   opera-next
>   opera
>   opera-stable

To install opera_12.16.1860 (32bit/64bit):

```
sudo apt-get install opera
```

To install opera-next_12.16.1860 (32bit/64bit)

```
sudo apt-get install opera-next
```

To install Opera browser-stable (64bit)

```
sudo apt-get install opera-stable
```

To install beta version (64bit):

```
sudo apt-get install opera-beta
```

To install developer version (32bit/64bit):

```
sudo apt-get install opera-developer
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have version 30.0.1835.59 installed, and the repository is in the list. I cant tick the package in the updater and in the terminal it is reported as skipped.

Comment: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS) (x86_64; Unity)

Comment: run the command `sudo apt-get install opera-stable`

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now I get some (Ihope) usefull messages. But I can look at it only in the next days. Maybe wednesday. The message says:

Comment: Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
opera-stable : Hängt ab von: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) aber 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1 soll installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) aber 2.32.4-0ubuntu1 soll installiert werden
Hängt ab von: libharfbuzz0b (>= 0.9.11) ist aber nicht installierbar
Hängt ab von: libnss3 (>= 2:3.15) aber 3.17.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 soll installiert werden

Comment: Hängt ab von: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) ist aber nicht installierbar
Hängt ab von: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) ist aber nicht installierbar
Hängt ab von: libstdc++6 (>= 4.8) aber 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 soll installiert werden
Empfiehlt: pepperflashplugin-nonfree ist aber nicht installierbar
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.

Comment: it would be nice to see those in english...

Comment: From what Google translated I'm assuming this http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Thank you JoKeR for your tip, but all the steps didn't work. To remove the opera-stable package and the attempt to intall it newly endet up in the same unresolved dependencies. So I dared to update to Ubuntu 14.04.2 - and installed opera-stable_30.0.1835.88 and it worked. No idea what the reason was but now it's fine for me. Thank you so much for your effort. THUMBS UP !

Comment: Off Topic - I'd like to invite you to a german beer ;-) but this is the web - in which part of the world would I find you, JoKeR ?

Comment: I'm glad you solved your issue... and thanks for the the deutschen bier :-) but I'm not in Germany for a pity I travel from place to place so not sure when I happen to be in Germany....